# pass a monadic function to where expects a normal function

Tags: haskell

If I have a function

```
pretty :: FilePath -> IO String
```

How can I pass it to

```
interact :: (String -> String) -> IO ()
```

?

Comment: You can't. The types don't match. Without doing something silly like `const "foo" . pretty`. Why don't you explain why you think you need to so that we can help with the actual problem :)

Comment: @jozefg I knew I can't, just wondering if there's something I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, `interact :: (String -> String) -> IO ()`, do notice the parentheses. That's a completely different type.

Writing

```
main = interact f
```

[is the same as writing](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/System-IO.html#interact)

```
main = do s <- getContents
          putStr (f s)
```

Now, `getContents :: IO String` i.e. the same type as `pretty filename`, with `filename :: FilePath`. So one can go instead of the other:

```
myinteraction filename f = 
    do
       s <- pretty filename
       putStr (f s)
```

But you can't just force it where it doesn't fit.